# Rebus and the Fridge

Tags: rebus

Rebus and the Fridge.  Apple Keynote is surprisingly effective to make these.[image]

What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> a six-pack in the fridge.

All these rebus puzzles seem really easy!

Comment: who was the fastest?  My internet was acting up.

Comment: @MichaelRize - I was 10:05:32, Oblong was 10:05:43, and Cool Guy was 10:06:30. Too easy :-p

Comment: yeah I will resist posting ones that are too easy.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like I'm going to sounds the alarm and lose points... Dam you Mr Fry

> six pack of alcoholic beverages

Comment: 10 seconds too late, but +1 anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is

> Six packs in the fridge

Or alternatively, A

> [Tiny mini fridge or a Six-pack-Sized fridge](http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/tiny-mini-fridge)